# askubuntu.com rule idea: Don't edit post titles unless you read the body first

Tags: discussion, edits

We should have a rule that says, don't edit posts unless you understand what the topic is...

Someone (not sure if it was a prank) edited my post without reading it and basically made the title and body ask for two different things. [How does one open the HUD from the command line.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137454/bash-script-help-for-hud)

Please stop doing that.

Answer (score -15, accepted):

OP is 100% correct!!! If we're not sure what a post is, we should ask the author before editing. What a great idea!

Comment: I love how logic is downvoted.

Comment: People have their own opinions. If they don't agree and think it is anything fro mmisinformational to libel, they may downvote.

Comment: This whole page is funny. It's like all the down voters are saying "I shouldn't have to read anything before I edit!!" So they downvote.

Comment: They have read the post before editing. If I had seen your post, I would have edited the same way as @JorgeCastro would have done. People(Including me) are downvoting because  they see you don't just want to just apologize and move on. All you want to do is to show your anger and dislike at practices that would often be done at AskUbuntu. If it was a misunderstanding, just agree it to being as such.

Comment: Wrong and wrong. If you had read anything, you would have seem my apology and his edits. Try harder next time.

Comment: Your retort was after his apology.

Comment: My retorts at *other* people.

Comment: you obviously don't just want to close this issue and move on, as you are simply aggravation the situation. I will not continue to argue with you. If you want to continue this, seek a ♦moderator and argue with him/her.

Comment: It is closed. I was nice enough to provide the correct answer. My responding to people who post is not being aggravated. It's my generosity; you're getting free logic. Enjoy.

Answer (score 14):

Now that this has been moved I will answer it. For the most part, you are right. However, the person that edited it DID indeed read your question and decided to give it more detail.

"BASH script help" can cover a wide variety, so he specialized it in order for a more concentrated crowd to see and be able to answer your question.

To prevent editing in the future you could make clearer questions or post elsewhere such as the Ubuntu forums to keep your post unabridged.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, the question was so poorly titled in the first place! Anyway it's fine now.

Comment: x2 No harm done, castro. I just got upset that it was worded against my original meaning and was left that way for a few hours. I'll be more clear in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, I personally believe that the editor should have left a comment requesting clarity and/or flagged it as very low quality.